# Where did the e's come from in this Normal Distribution exercise?

Tags: normal-distribution, density-function

[image: https://imgur.com/gallery/VvHcRf1]

I get up to the very last part where I circled it in red.

I get that it's $$1 - P(\text{exactly 0 person over 6ft2in}) - P(\text{exactly 1 person over 6ft2in}) = P(\text{at least 2})$$

What I don't understand is why they are equal to $e^{-μ} + e^{-μ} μ$

Where did $e^{-μ}$ even come from?

Comment: Plug $x=0$ and $x=1$ into the following: $$\frac{\mu^x e^{- \mu} }{x!}$$

Comment: It comes from the Poisson approximation: $Pr(X = k) = \dfrac {\mu^ke^{-\mu}}{k!}$